# Compare a field with a field in a related table in Prisma ORM

Tags: mysql, prisma

I am trying to filter results by comparing one related table field with another related table field.

(simplified situation)
At our institute we offer **Courses** that contain **Lessons** where a **Teacher** can be assigned to.
**Courses** are provided by **Departments**.
**Teachers** are from a **Department**.
We want to find all **Lessons** where the **Teachers** is from **another Department** than the **Course** that the **Lesson** is part of.

In SQL this can be achieved like this:

```sql
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  Lesson l
JOIN Teacher t ON
  t.id = l.teacher_id
JOIN Course c ON
  c.id = l.course_id
WHERE 
  c.department_id <> t.department_id
```

Currently I use a raw query using `Prisma.sql`, but I would like to use Prisma client API. I tried something like this:

```js
return await prisma.lesson.findMany({
  where: {
    Teacher: {
      department_id: { equals: ????? }
    }
  }
})
```

But I have no idea what to place at the `?????`.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of filter using the Prisma client API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/15068.

A new preview feature is running for comparing columns in the same table (https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#compare-columns-in-the-same-table), that also triggered the discussion to find a resolution for your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Comparing columns in the same table is possible in Prisma using **4.3.0**
Make sure the Prisma version should be >= 4.3.0

Comment: OP specifically requested that columns should be compared across related tables.